# How To Add Temporary Class, when the Other Active Class is Removed

Tags: javascript, animation, tabs

In this case I just wanna add transition from `display: flex` to `display: none` in array. Adding temporary `.content-show` `class` into my `<div>`, so the condition is when the other `active` `class` is removed, I added a `.content-show` `class` into it for a transition, `setTimeout` to 1500ms to the `.content-show` `class` then remove it. But, when I inspected it, the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')` warning showed up. And the error is located in the `function removeActive()`, where I commented it on the right side. I already did in my tabs `class` above on the `function removeActiveTab()`, but in this condition, I'm literally stuck. Please help me to get through this one.

**Here's my code :**

```js
//Toggle the toggle and menu wrapper
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
const menuTrigger = document.querySelector('.toggle'),
      menu = document.querySelector('.tabs');

menuTrigger.onclick = openMenu
  
function openMenu() {
      menuTrigger.classList.toggle('active');
      menu.classList.toggle('active');
}
  
})

//Add active class of tab on page load
var ready = (callback) => {
  if (document.readyState != "loading") callback();
  else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
}
ready(() => {
  if(window.angular) return;
  document.querySelectorAll('.tab:first-child').forEach( first => {
    first.classList.add('active');
  })
  document.querySelectorAll('.content-item:first-child').forEach( first => {
    first.classList.add('active');
  })
})

//Add & remove class tab, contents, & menu on click
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=> {
  let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
  let content = document.querySelectorAll('.content-item');
  let menuW = document.querySelector('.tabs');
  let toggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
  
        for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {            
            tabs[i].addEventListener('click', () => tabClick(i));
        }

        function tabClick(currentTab) {
            removeActive();
            removeActiveTab();
            tabs[currentTab].classList.add('active');
            content[currentTab].classList.add('active');
            iframe = content[currentTab].querySelector('iframe');
            iframe.setAttribute('src', iframe.getAttribute('data-src'));
        }

        function removeActive() {
            for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
                tabs[i].classList.remove('active');
                content[i].classList.remove('active');
                content[i].classList.add('content-show');      //Can't add class
                setTimeout(function() {                        //So this one,
                  content[i].classList.remove('content-show'); //can't remove class
                },2500);                                       //What should I do :(
                iframe = content[i].querySelector('iframe');
                iframe.removeAttribute('src');
            }
        }
        function removeActiveTab() {
            menuW.classList.remove('active');
            menuW.classList.add('show-tab');
            setTimeout(function() {
              menuW.classList.remove('show-tab');},500);
            toggle.classList.remove('active');
        }
})
```

```css
.container-tab {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 65px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: top;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
    
        .wrapperleft {
            width: 10%;
            height: 100%;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
    
        .wrapperright {
            width: 90%;
            height: 100%;
            justify-content: center;
         }

        .toggle {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: red;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: 1.5s ease-in-out all;
        }

        .toggle.active {
            background-color: blue;
            transition: 1.5s ease-in-out all;
        }

        .tabs {
            display: none;
            overflow: hidden;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            width: 340px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 10%;
        }

        .show-tab {
            display: flex;
            animation-name: menu-out;
            animation-duration: 0.5s;
        }
        
        @keyframes menu-out {
            0% {display: flex; opacity: 1;}
           99% {display: flex; opacity: 0;}
          100% {display: none; opacity: 0;}
        }

        .tabs.active{
            display: flex;
            animation-name: menu-in;
            animation-duration: 0.5s;
        }

        @keyframes menu-in {
            0% {display: none; opacity: 0;}
            1% {display: flex; opacity: 0.01;}
          100% {display: flex; opacity: 1;}
        }

        .tab {
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .tab.active {
            background-color: rgb(250, 97, 9);
        }

        .content {
            width: 100vw;
            margin-top: 50px;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .content-item {
            display: none;
            padding: 0px;
            border: none;
            position: absolute;
        }
        
        .content-show {
            display: flex;
            animation-name: fade-out;
            animation-duration: 2.5s;
        }
        
        @keyframes fade-out {
            0% {
                opacity: 1;
                display: flex;
            }
            99% {
                opacity: 0;
                display: flex;
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 0;
                display: none;
            }
        }

        .content-item.active {
            display: flex;
            border: none;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100%;
            animation-name: fade-in;
            animation-duration: 2.5s;
        }

        @keyframes fade-in {
            0% {
                display: none;
                opacity: 0;
            }
            1% {
                display: block;
                opacity: 0.01;
            }
            100%{
                display: block;
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }

        .content-iframe {
            border: none;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 50vh;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container-tab">
      <div class="wrapperleft">
        <div class="toggle"></div>
        <div class="tabs">
            <div class="tab">Tokyo</div>
            <div class="tab">Paris</div>
            <div class="tab">Washington</div>
            <div class="tab">Jakarta</div>
            <div class="tab">London</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapperright">

      </div>
</div>
  <div class="container-content">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-item">
              <div class="content-wrapper1">
                <div class="content-wrapper2">
                  <div class="content-wrapper3">
                    <iframe class= "content-iframe" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-item">
              <div class="content-wrapper1">
                <div class="content-wrapper2">
                  <div class="content-wrapper3">
                    <iframe class= "content-iframe" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-item">
              <div class="content-wrapper1">
                <div class="content-wrapper2">
                  <div class="content-wrapper3">
                    <iframe class= "content-iframe" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-item">
              <div class="content-wrapper1">
                <div class="content-wrapper2">
                  <div class="content-wrapper3">
                    <iframe class= "content-iframe" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-item">
              <div class="content-wrapper1">
                <div class="content-wrapper2">
                  <div class="content-wrapper3">
                    <iframe class= "content-iframe" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please Any JavaScript Master here Help me to solve this code. Thank You So Much Everyone, Have a Nice Day!

Comment: You are calling the `add` method in multiple places there, please clarify _where_ the error occurs.

Comment: @CBroe I already mention the error is in the JS where I commented it on the right side. On the `function removeActive()`, that's what I confused. The other one I did on the `function removeActiveTab()` but, it's not an array, while the error is an array. Please help me to solve this..

Comment: Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Still hoping someone to answer or maybe just commenting